# Transaction History With ETH API

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, private-blockchain

I working on Private Block chain and doing code GoLang for all block chain relate functionalities. I am making on API's to interact with  my Pvt Block chain instead of using web3js.
Now I want to view transaction history of specific accounts, how I can achieve that with GoLand and ETH API.

Regards
AKM.

Comment: AFAIK there's no such functionality, you have to implement it by indexing each transaction, and internal transaction recording transfers between accounts, and generated by mining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Go you can't import an external package if the import path contains the word *internal* otherwise you get the error `use of internal package not allowed`. The *ethapi* is an internal package.

[source](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit)